Firebear Import/Export won't read all rows of the given CSV file on import
I am attempting to import products from a CSV file containing 7763 products, but only 6459 rows are being checked. I can confirm that products are being left out through the products page on the backend.
I get no error message. It says that the import was a success. With that being said, the importation of the products that ARE being checked works as intended.
I first theorized that the products themselves were the problem. That they were badly formatted or something similar. I can however confirm that this is not the case. I created a separate CSV file containing only 1 product that I know was left out and the import was a success and the product shows up both on the front and backend.
Any help is appreciated. I would however like to refrain from PHP scripts.
Thank you.

Make sure you have installed the latest version of Firebear. I faced this issue many times but its was seems the sku repeating/duplicate in my case.
